# how to get child element from SOAP body?

Tags: java, soap

How can I get clientCode from requestHeader which is located under SOAP body?

```
<soapenv:Body>
      <ser:GS>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <requestHeader>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <req:clientCode>KL7MU</req:clientCode>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <req:clientUsername>BLABLA</req:clientUsername>
         </requestHeader>
      </ser:GS>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

I try to get but `iterator.hasNext()` returns `false`.

```
SOAPBody soapBody = context.getMessage().getSOAPBody();

java.util.Iterator iterator = soapBody.getChildElements();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = (SOAPBodyElement) iterator.next();
  String val = bodyElement.getValue();
  System.out.println("The Value is:" + val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use wsdl to generate java class:

```
wsimport stock.wsdl -b stock.xml -b stock.xjb
wsimport -d generated http://example.org/stock?wsdl
```

Then you can call SOAP services as local methods.

Some other tools:

wsdl2javawizard: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2javawizard/

apache cxf: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html

Comment: I don't think so. Specially when I am inside an axis2 handler. There should be a way to get element values from the body

Comment: Agreed with @Marlo especially when you deal with some kind of SOAP Console that should have deal with plenty of different WSDLs

Answer (score 0):

instead of getting form SOAP message body 
try the child elements form SOAP message header like  context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader();
details :http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-client-side/

Answer (score -1):

You can get the values like in axiom,

```
SOAPEnvelope mes = messageContext.getEnvelope();
SOAPHeader mesh = mes.getHeader();
SOAPBody mesb = mes.getBody();
OMElement messageId = mesh.getFirstChildWithName(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing","MessageID"));
String messageIDStr = messageId.getText();
OMElement bodyChild = mesb.getFirstElement();
OMElement remoteAddress = bodyChild.getFirstChildWithName(new QName(
                                    "http://YourNameSpaceURI",
                                    "remoteAddress"));
String remoteAddressStr = remoteAddress.getText();
```